VBA TextToColumns function doesn't work in shared workbook
I have already solved here the question of splitting text into columns via the TextToColumns function. But now I have a problem, I had to set this excel as shared and this function doesn't work for me.
Can this please be replaced by some other function that would work in a shared workbook?
Private Sub Generate_Click()
  Dim destRng As Range
    If Selection.Columns.Count = 1 And ActiveCell.Column = 7 Then
    'Set destRng = Range("G4")  instead this
    
        Selection.TextToColumns , Destination:=Range("H" & Selection.Row), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="-", Other:=False, OtherChar:="_"
    
        Else
        MsgBox "Mark only column G"
        End If
    
End Sub

The separator character is a dash "-"
EDIT :
Is it possible to modify this code to run on all selected cells? Because now it only works on one selected cell :
Private Sub Generate_Click()
  Dim splitVals As Variant
  Dim totalVals As Long
    If Selection.Columns.Count = 1 And ActiveCell.Column = 7 Then
   
        splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "-")
        totalVals = UBound(splitVals)

        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals

        Else
        MsgBox "Mark only column G"
        End If
    
End Sub


If you are on Excel 365 you could use the TEXTSPLIT formula to achieve the splitting and then replace the formula by its values:
Private Sub Generate_Click()
  
    If Selection.Columns.Count = 1 And ActiveCell.Column = 7 Then
        Dim rgTarget As Range, c As Range, rgValues As Range
        
        Set rgTarget = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Selection.Row).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count)
        With rgTarget
            .Formula2 = "=TEXTSPLIT(G" & Selection.Row & ",""-"")"
            
            Set rgValues = .Resize(, .CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Column + .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - .Column) 'get range to which the formula spills
            rgValues.Value = rgValues.Value ' replace formula by value
            
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Mark only column G"
    End If

End Sub


Thank you for your help, but when workbook is shared it only split text into the first column and ignores the rest of the text and columns, but when I don't share it works and splits it into all columns, can you fix this somehow?

Looks like this is another restriction of shared workbooks - I didn't know about that

Hello, is it possible to modify the code so that it runs whenever something is inserted into the cell? Because I've been struggling but I have a code that works even with a shared worksheet, it just doesn't work when multiple rows are selected. Could you please help me either to make it work also when selecting multiple cells or to start it after inserting some value into the cell?
